# Cast string date as a date

Tags: c#, date, datetime, casting

I'm using ASP.NET to load data from a database to display the date of an item purchased, however it is also showing a time stamp of 12:00:00 AM beside it.

How can I print the value so that it only shows the date?

```
private void UpdateInventory(int index)
{
    DataView inventoryTable = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    DataRowView row = (DataRowView)inventoryTable[index];

    currentInventory.fac_ID = row["fac_ID"].ToString();
    currentInventory.inv_Quantity = row["inv_Quantity"].ToString();
    currentInventory.inv_Purchase_Date = row["inv_Purchase_Date"].ToString();

    lblFacilityID.Text = currentInventory.fac_ID;
    lblQuantity.Text = currentInventory.inv_Quantity;
    lblPurchaseDate.Text = currentInventory.inv_Purchase_Date;
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateInventory(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex);
}

public string fac_ID { get; set; }
public string inv_Quantity { get; set; }
public string inv_Purchase_Date { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need anything too special, but just want to omit the time, you could use this:

```
lblPurchaseDate.Text
    = Convert.ToDateTime(row["inv_Purchase_Date"]).ToShortDateString();
```

This will display something like:

```
2/22/2014
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ToShortDateString` method:

```
currentInventory.inv_Purchase_Date  = (row["inv_Quantity"] as DateTime).ToShortDateString();
```

Or use pass a string argument [specify a format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
currentInventory.inv_Purchase_Date = (row["inv_Quantity"] as DateTime).ToString("d MMMM YYYY");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`DateTime.ToString(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - for example:

```
currentInventory.inv_Purchase_Date =
    Convert.ToDateTime(row["inv_Purchase_Date"]).ToString("d");
```

For the `string` argument, you can use `"d"`, which will yield the same results as `DateTime.ToShortDateString()` [as MSDN explains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); but you also have a lot of flexibility to use other [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) short-date format strings.

Note that if your code cannot assume a culture, you should consider conversion options/overloads that leverage `IFormatProvider` - for example:

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("en-US"); // or "ja-JP" etcetera

// ...

currentInventory.inv_Purchase_Date =
    DateTime.Parse(row["inv_Purchase_Date"].ToString(), ci).ToString("d", ci);
```